# What causes a Tekton step to fail?

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

Steps succeed or fail based on the output of the command or script they run, but I'm not clear on how exactly this works. Does any output to `stderr` cause the step to fail? If not, how exactly does Tekton determine if a step has failed or succeeded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about the exit code of each steps in your Task.

If one of your steps exits with a non-0 code, then your Task failed. Otherwise it succeeded.